# Additional button to bsmodal footer shiny

Tags: button, shiny, bootstrap-modal, footer

In addition to the default close button, I would like to add a button located on the bottom left of my bsmodal.

I tried:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui<-fluidPage(
  actionButton("tabBut", "View Table"),
  bsModal("modalExample", "Modal Example", "tabBut", size = "large",tags$div(class="modal-footer",tags$button(type="button",class="btn btn-primary mr-auto","data-dismiss"="modal","Done")))
)

server<-function(input, output){

}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment of @kraggle, you can use something like this:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
        .modal-footer div {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
        }
        .modal-footer div button {
          min-width: 0;
          max-width: 250px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }"
      )
    )
  ),
  actionButton("tabBut", "View Table"),
)

server<-function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$tabBut, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = 'Modal Example',
        footer = div(
          actionButton("done", "Some button for Done"),
          modalButton('Close')
        )
      )
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On way to handle this would be to use shiny `showModal` and `modalDialog` as shown in the below example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui<-fluidPage(
  actionButton("tabBut", "View Table"),
  #bsModal("modalExample", "Modal Example", "tabBut", size = "large",tags$div(class="modal-footer",tags$button(type="button",class="btn btn-primary mr-auto","data-dismiss"="modal","Done")))
)

server<-function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$tabBut, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = 'Modal Example',
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton("done", "Some button for Done"),
          modalButton('Close')
        )
      )
    )
  })

}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: That places it to the left of the modal close button, not on the left side of the modal.